# Dynamically create radio buttons arranged in a table format in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I basically want to create a table full of dynamically created radioButtons where I can handle their individual clicks.

The row and column headers will both contain their own text headings, and the accompanying cells contain the radioButtons.

Comment: This sounds like you are asking someone to write your code for you. You'll get more traction if you say what you want to do, show your research and code, and tell us what results you get.

Comment: @jdv I've been able to find my way around it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been able to answer the question. Find attached the code and screenshot for your perusal. Scrolling is horizontal when the screen is portrait and vertical in landscape mode. Enjoy!

[image: Screenshot of dynamically created table in Flutter]

```
     import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

    class TableView extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _TableViewState createState() => _TableViewState();
    }

    class _TableViewState extends State<TableView> {
      List rowHeaders = new List();
      List columnHeaders = new List();
      Map selected = new Map();

      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        saveHeaders(); //Iterate and store all Row and column Headers
      }

      saveHeaders() {
        //Saving All Headers
        columnHeaders.addAll(["Excellent", "Very Good", "Good", "Poor"]);
        rowHeaders.addAll(["MTN", "Vodafone", "Tigo", "Expresso", "Glo"]);
      }

      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return new Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: new Text("TableView"),
            ),
            body: new OrientationBuilder(builder: (context, orientation) {
              return Center(
                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                scrollDirection: orientation ==
                        Orientation
                            .portrait //Handle Scroll when Orientation is changed
                    ? Axis.horizontal
                    : Axis.vertical,
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new Container(
                      color: Colors.blueGrey[200],
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0, bottom: 10.0),
                      alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          //headers
                          new Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                            child: new Row(
                                children: [
                              new Container(
                                alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
                                width: 140.0,
                                margin: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                    top: 5.0, bottom: 5.0, right: 3.0, left: 3.0),
                                child: Text(
                                  //Leave an empty text in Row(0) and Column (0)
                                  "",
                                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[800]),
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                ),
                              )
                            ]..addAll(columnHeaders
                                    .map((header) => new Container(
                                          alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
                                          width: 120.0,
                                          margin: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                              top: 5.0,
                                              bottom: 5.0,
                                              right: 3.0,
                                              left: 3.0),
                                          child: new Text(
                                            header,
                                            style:
                                                TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[800]),
                                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                          ),
                                        ))
                                    .toList())),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    )
                  ]..addAll(createRows()), //Create Rows
                ),
              ));
            }));
      }

      List<Widget> createRows() {
        List<Widget> allRows = new List(); //For Saving all Created Rows

        for (int i = 0; i < rowHeaders.length; i++) {
          List<Widget> singleRow = new List(); //For creating a single row
          for (int j = 0; j < columnHeaders.length; j++) {
            singleRow.add(Container(
                alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
                width: 120.0,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: 6.0, bottom: 6.0, right: 3.0, left: 3.0),
                child: Radio(
                  value: j, //Index of created Radio Button
                  groupValue: selected[rowHeaders[i]] !=
                          null //If groupValue is equal to value, the radioButton will be selected
                      ? selected[rowHeaders[i]]
                      : "",
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    this.setState(() {
                      selected[rowHeaders[i]] =
                          value; //Adding selected rowName with its Index in a Map tagged "selected"
                      print("${rowHeaders[i]} ==> $value");
                    });
                  },
                )));
          }
          //Adding single Row to allRows widget
          allRows.add(new Container(
              child: new Row(
            children: [
              new Container(
                alignment: FractionalOffset.centerLeft,
                width: 140.0,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: 6.0, bottom: 6.0, right: 3.0, left: 10.0),
                child:
                    Text(rowHeaders[i], style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[800])),
              )
            ]..addAll(singleRow), //Add single row here
          )));
        }
        return allRows; //Return all single rows
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

first you must create an array type of radio button with suitable identifier :
    3 * 3 Table of radio buttons Just like this :

```
*   *   *
*   *   *
*   *   *


RadioButton [,] r=new RadioButton[3,3];
```

then set location and call initialize method for in  :

```
for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
    {
        r[i,j]=new RadioButton();
        r[i,j].Tag=I.toString()+"-"+j.toString();
        r[i,j].top=30+j*30;
        r[i,j].top=30+i*30;
        r[i,j].click+=new EvantHandler(*/the method that you whant to call when click in each radio button*/);
    }
}
```

when event handler method called you can easily find that which radio button was clicked! from tag value of each radio button